# Hot to draw a specific border around a QR-code?

Tags: graphics, border

As the treasurer of an association it's my duty to send out yearly invoices for membership dues. I use `scrlttr2` on `LuaLaTeX` for that, and it's working fine. To allow for easier payment, I am using a QR-Code containing the relevant payment info. That, too, works largely as expected:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[forget]{qrcode}

% \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Not used due to conflict with qrcode

\setkomavar{signature}{Nomen Nescio, Honcho in Chief} 

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{To: All members}

\opening{Dear all,}

Please pay up!

\closing{Kthanksbye,}

\begin{textblock*}{10cm}(13.5cm,22cm)%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{7cm} % use \? for newline, all spaces must be prefixed with \
\qrcode[height=4cm,level="M"]{BCD\?001\?1\?SCT\?ABCDATWW\?Applepie\ Appreciation\ Society\?AT611904300234573201\?EUR90\?\?MyUniqueReference\?\?}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{textblock*}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Apparently there is some software or app, however, that doesn't recognize these codes unless they have a specific border drawn around them like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to draw that border with `LaTeX` (`TikZ`?), or do I have to use a transparent image of the border and just position it on top of the created QR-Code? (Using `\AddToShipoutPicture` or something similar is my plan B at this point.)

Comment: How about adding a simple `\fbox` to it? If this does not work I would suffest the `tcolorbox`package.

Comment: Is the text on the right side mandatory, or only the frame?

Comment: I don't actually know, to be honest. I'll need to get in touch with that user and test, but I think without the text would be fine for now.

Comment: Actually, the text was relatively easy. I used `\rotatebox{90}{\colorbox{white}{Zahlen mit Code}}` insided another `\begin{textblock*}` and got it all to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your comments and contributions I was able to get it to work:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[forget]{qrcode}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,ngerman]{babel}

\setkomavar{signature}{Nomen Nescio, Honcho in Chief} 

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{To: All members}

\opening{Dear all,}

Please pay up!

\closing{Kthanksbye,}

\begin{textblock*}{10cm}(13.5cm,22cm)%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{6,75cm} % use \? for newline, all spaces must be prefixed with \

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,grow to right by=-17mm]
\qrcode[height=4cm,level="M"]{BCD\?001\?1\?SCT\?ABCDATWW\?Applepie\ Appreciation\ Society\?AT611904300234573201\?EUR90\?\?MyUniqueReference\?\?}
\end{tcolorbox}

    \end{minipage}
  \end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{2cm}(18.25cm,23cm)%
\rotatebox{90}{\colorbox{white}{Zahlen mit Code}}
\end{textblock*}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without the text I would suggest:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[forget]{qrcode}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}


% \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Not used due to conflict with qrcode

\setkomavar{signature}{Nomen Nescio, Honcho in Chief} 

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{To: All members}

\opening{Dear all,}

Please pay up!

\closing{Kthanksbye,}

\begin{textblock*}{10cm}(13.5cm,22cm)%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{7cm} % use \? for newline, all spaces must be prefixed with \

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,grow to right by=-17mm]
\qrcode[height=4cm,level="M"]{BCD\?001\?1\?SCT\?ABCDATWW\?Applepie\ Appreciation\ Society\?AT611904300234573201\?EUR90\?\?MyUniqueReference\?\?}
\end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{textblock*}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to get it to work: Using another `\begin{textblock*}` environment the text, it's working good now.